# Disable Offline sync on libraries in a sitecollection SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, office365

I need to disable offline sync on 900 subsites and want to do this programmatically but I can't find any ways to make it work. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through each site in each site collection. On each site loop through each list and set this parameter:

```
$list.ExcludeFromOfflineClient = true;
```

Full example:

```
$site = Get-SPSite <your site collection url>
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{   
    write-host "Site: $web"
    foreach($list in $web.lists){
        $list.ExcludeFromOfflineClient = true
        $list.update();
    }
}
$site.dispose()
```

Comment: I've tried this but doesn't work, after some reading it seems like this only works on premis and not online. 
Have you used this for disable sync online?

Comment: Sorry, i am only working on premise, i added a working example but i cannot tell you if online this works too :(

Comment: also instead of true you can try using 1

Answer (score 0):

The August 2016 release of the CSOM for SharePoint Online exposes `ExcludeFromOfflineClient` on both the `List` and `Web` classes.

https://www.clevershare.nl/2016/09/new-sharepoint-csom-version-for-sharepoint-online-august-2016/